# What is the black box behind the guest side of the desk on The Daily Show?

Tags: the-daily-show, talk-shows

There is a black box on the floor on the guest side of the desk on *The Daily Show* and I've been wondering for a while what it is for.

Does anyone know?

At first I thought it was a sound monitor (as used by singers in concert), but that doesn't really make much sense: the guests can hear themselves fine.

It seems so awkwardly placed that it must be of some importance, but I can't imagine what.

[image]

Comment: Maybe a table for the gust to place items out of view? Like a book or a prop, they know they'll need during the interview.

Comment: I've noticed (as of 1.1.18) that the "black box" is no longer there. So it is a "mystery" without an answer . . . 